# How to clone a object to a object of Object class?

Tags: java, class, object, clone

As I have learned, `Object class` is a top level class and it is a parent of all classes. If we do not know a type of class at compile time, we can assign it to a object of Object class.

I am trying to `clone` a object to object of a `Object class`. Also trying to get the object from `HashMap` which is already instantiated. I am having problem in doing this. Can you figure out it and explain the right ways of doing it? I have commented in which lines I get compile time error. My main doubts are:

- If a parent class' object can be used for cloning, then it must work with Object class too as it is top level class.
- And how to access object from map and use it for method call and cloning.

Code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


class Sample {
    public void call(){

}

}
class Question extends Sample implements Cloneable {
@Override
    public void call(){
    System.out.println("hello");
}
@Override
    public Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{  
    return super.clone();  
    }  

public static void main(String args[]) throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    Map<Character,Object> map=new HashMap();
    Question s=new Question();
    Sample q=new Question();
    Sample cl=(Question)s.clone();
    Object ob=(Question)s.clone();//no compile time error
    map.put('o',s);
    s.call();//hello
    q.call();//hello
    cl.call();/hello
    ob.call();//Compile time error: cannot find  symbol call
    map.get('o').call();//Compile time error: cannot find  symbol call
    Object obj=(Question) (map.get('o')).clone();// Compile time error: clone has protected access in Object

}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: help understanding the use of interfaces as a data type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968485/java-help-understanding-the-use-of-interfaces-as-a-data-type) [it's the same with subclasses]

Comment: just a piece of advice. The first character of a classname should always be an uppercase (convention): i.e.  `sample` should be `Sample`

Comment: @bvdb Thanks . Updated. !

Comment: @RC. Sorry I did not understand from the other thread. If you have time, can u elaborate a bit with respect to this program?

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: @EJP will stick to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line can be simplified

```
Object ob=(Question)s.clone();//no compile time error
// the cast is unnecessary:
Object ob= s.clone();
```

But like you said, the `ob` will still contain a `Question` object. The problem is that once you start using this `ob` reference, java just knows it contains a value of `Object`, or a subclass of it. So for java `ob` could be a `Number` or a `String` or an `Airplane`.

```
Object ob = "airplane";
```

Once it gets to the line `ob.call()` it refuses. Because it's not sure that the `ob` object has a `call` method. For example, if it was a `String` or a `Number` it would be impossible.

For this reason **you have to perform a simple cast first:**

```
((Question)ob).call(); 
// or 
((Sample)ob).call();
```

Just let java know that it's an object with a call method.

**The map#call issue has the same reasoning:**

```
map.get('o').call();
//could be any of these
((Sample)map.get('o')).call();
((Question)map.get('o')).call();
```

**But the last problem is more tricky.** Actually a lot gets clear when you split up your statement in multiple lines:

```
Object obj=(Question) (map.get('o')).clone();
// would be the same like writing:
Object value = map.get('o');
Object value2 = value.clone();
Object obj = (Question) value2; // The (Question) cast is actually unnecessary.
```

The problem is in the `value.clone()` step. It is true that the `Object` class has a `clone` method, but it's marked as `protected` whereas the `clone` methods in your `Question` and `Sample` classes are `public`.
So in short `Object#clone` is not accessible ; `Sample#clone` and `Question#clone` are accessible.

```
// so you want this:
Object value = map.get('o');
Object value2 = ((Question)value).clone(); // add a cast here
Object obj = value2;
```

If you prefer to do it all in 1 line:

```
Object obj=((Question) (map.get('o'))).clone();
```

Comment: Wow, that was perfect.can you explain me about accessing the objects from HashMap?

Comment: Sorry actually (Question)ob.call(); too throws a compile time error.

Comment: I stand corrected, added braces `((Question)ob).call()`

Comment: ((Question)ob).call() is working well. thanks a ton (Y)